# Stop Piston's error catching

Tags: python, django, django-piston

I'm using Piston with Django. Anytime there's an error in my handler code, I get a simplified, text-only description of the error in my http response, which gives me much less information that Django does when it's reporting errors. How can I stop Piston catching errors in this way?

Answer (score 5):

In your settings.py file, add `PISTON_DISPLAY_ERRORS = False` this will cause exceptions to be raised allowing them to be shown as expected in the Django debug error page when you are using `DEBUG = True`.

There are a few cases when the exception won't propagate properly. I've seen it happen when Piston says that the function definition doesn't match, but haven't looked to see why...

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could try to override `Resource.error_handle`, and instead of using the default implementation:

https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/src/c4b2d21db51a/piston/resource.py#cl-248

just re-raise the original exception.